# How can i remove background from face image using PRNet and get an image containing only face?

Tags: python, deep-learning, face-detection, 3d-reconstruction

PRNet is a 3D reconstruction code in github[text](https://github.com/yfeng95/PRNet), It can get the 3D vertices and corresponding colours from a single image. However, i don't know how to use the 3D vertices to generate face reconstruction area so as to face matting.

Need some very good people to give me an idea or code